# Which format mask of phone number is safe for input for all countries?

Tags: regex, validation, phone-number

I am making an input form for registering employees. I thought the number format in any country would fit in `/\+(\d+)-\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d/`, where (\d+) is country code I assume to have different length and next goes exactly 10 digits. I need to create input fields and validation rules to make input as protected and unambiguous as possible but I am also worried if there could be actual numbers that don't fit this regex. Is there a safe international standard way of writing numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no particular format which you can apply for all the countries phone number.

However `\d*` will be one of the choice with which you can proceed with but that too is not the best.

You may check [National conventions for writing telephone numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers)

Comment: I do not think hyphens, spaces or whatever are that important, as this is only for convenience. I was mostly concerned about an overall number of digits next to the country code. Are there countries with more or less digits?

Comment: @German:- Yes there are countries having different number of digits.

Comment: @German:- The wiki link which I have added in the answer will help you in identifying those countries. For example Netherland have 8 digit number and India has 10 digit. Now there is a difference in digits in mobile and landline number as well